# How to interact with custom numpy dtypes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to add some points together and custom dtypes do not behave as `ndarray`s. The following is code I'm trying to use:

```python
self.center = np.dtype([('x', np.uint16), ('y', np.uint16)])

nd0 = np.array((1, 2))
nd1 = np.array((3, 4))
print(nd0 + nd1)

c0 = np.array((1, 2), dtype=self.center)
c1 = np.array((3, 4), dtype=self.center)
print(c0 + c1)
```

The second `print` yields an error:

```python
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types 
dtype([('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<u2')]) 
dtype([('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<u2')]) 
dtype([('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<u2')])
```

Is standard practice to create a custom function to handle unique `dtype`? `c0` and `c1` are of type `numpy.void`, whereas `nd0` and `nd1` are `numpy.ndarray`. I attempted to cast with `numpy.asarray` but it still fails to add the two.

I wanted to average the centers of two objects. The `center` named field is nested in another named array and I thought it'd be easier to do something like:

```python
new_center = (pop[i]['center'] + pop[j]['center']) / 2.0
```

Rather than:

```python
new_center = (pop[i][0] + pop[j][0]) / 2.0
```

for readability and maintenance.

Comment: Math functions don't work on structured arrays like this.  You can though do the math on the individual fields.

Comment: Structured arrays are most useful when they contain a mix of dtypes, say string labels, plus integer and float values.  I don't think they should be used just as a labeling device.

Comment: It is possible to define a structure that has overlapping field definitions, such that 'xy' could access the same two values as 'x' and 'y'.  But the syntax for doing that is harder to remember, so I won't try to demonstrate if off hand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503565/make-a-numpy-array-with-shape-and-offset-argument-in-another-style demonstrates how to access separate fields as well as their union.  And an earlier example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349116/no-binary-operators-for-structured-arrays-in-numpy